# Symfony SessionHandler Warning

Tags: php, symfony, session, php-8, php-7.4

when I try to run a especifical project on my computer, symfony show me this error:

Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/opt/alt/php74/var/lib/php/session\sess_rt7p5374uhjagiperqv83aej38, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

I'm use symfony 5.4 and PHP 8

Answer (score 0):

I found this line session.save_path = "/opt/alt/php74/var/lib/php/session"
in .user.ini file and I changed it and now it's working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with Symfony's side. You can set proper path at `session.save_path` in your `php.ini`

```
session.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

The folder you use should be under your domain/account but not accessible through a Web browser. It also needs to have world-writable permissions on it based on user/role.